# Dumping CPU cache contents, step by step

Tags: debugging, cpu-cache

My assumptions are simple ones at this point. This is what I'd assume for dumping L3:

- Stop normal execution / operations which might affect cache state.
- Where `A` is the starting memory location of what's currently in L3, read all locations from `A` to `A + L3width - 1`, displaying each.
- Do some ordinary program processing which affects the cache state, keeping track of latest `A`.
- Repeat from the top.

Q1: What incorrect assumptions have I made above? What have I left out? More detail please.

Q2: Is there any way to avoid changing the cache state when I write out the dump?

Q3: Would this process change for cache levels 2 and 1, other than using a different width and waiting a shorter time for the data to arrive?

Comment: If you are looking to prove the point for a proposed HW support then you should learn cache architecture first.

Comment: @Elalfer No, that is not my intent.

Comment: Then please edit your `EDIT` as it is a proposal for a HW support and not the prove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A.Q1. You can not be exactly sure what is in the cache right now. Therefore this algorithm doesn't really make sense. You might expect most of the data to be in the cache if you read A sequentially from `A` till `A+L3width-1` and avoid doing ANYTHING else, but it is more or less bringing data to $ and expect it to stay there for some (short) time.

A.Q2. Nope. No way

A.Q3. Of course it would, even more than L3

Comment: Er... Your A to Q1 makes no sense. The whole point of dumping the cache is to *find out* what's in it. And yes, since each cache level is a contiguous subset of memory, a sequential read of only those locations is going to avoid corrupting the state, no? What I am reading into this, though, is that OS background activities may be corrupting the cache state even as one is busy reading it. Lastly, I don't know what $ is. Q2: Not such a big deal, that.

Comment: `$` == `Cache` ;) Cache is not a contiguous subset of memory! This is where you are wrong on the first place. Cache consists of $-lines (64bytes for Intel arch). So L3$ might contain just a subset of [A,A+L3width-1] if any.

Comment: Trust me, there are no ways to find out what is in the $... And how do you expect the data to get to the $ on the first place?

Comment: Wrong. Read [this](http://www.cse.psu.edu/~xydong/files/proceedings/DAC2011/data/papers/2009/074.pdf) and you will appreciate that it is indeed possible to dump cache with integrity, even while the processor is running. However, it probably takes a very specific environment, maybe a microkernel that precludes any background processes running rampant and trashing cache state. If I cannot guarantee same, my question becomes moot.

Comment: In order to do that one have to have an access to CPU "debug" interface. And in this article they are showing algorithm to dump internal state by `ways` & `sets`. There are no ways to do it via publically available instruction sets

Comment: In this article they just propose a HW support for doing that, and used CPU & cache simulators to do POC

Comment: You're right. My mistake. I'm still not convinced that it is impossible to dump state, but again, given an environment like Windows, I doubt it would be possible to guarantee cache integrity for a single running application.

Comment: @NickWiggill, You can't guarantee anything, even with non interruptable OS/microkernel, the CPU itself may decide to power down at some point. The code you use to read the cache is also going to get filled into the cache level (the unified ones, usually L2/L3) and throw out some of the data, the page table, stack, etc.. - all are going to interfere. Last but not least - you don't know how the replacement mechanism work, no one guarantees that consecutive lines will have the same lifespan.

Comment: OS doesn't really matter. $ may have data from multiple processes at the same time. Let's continue this discussion a bit later - quite busy for now ;-)